# Removing extension of a file name in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt to get a file name from the user:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select an image file"),"d:\\",tr("Image files(*.tiff *.tif )"));
```

It works, but I need the file name *without its extension*, is it possible in Qt?? 
whenn I try :

```
QString f = QFileInfo(fileName).fileName();
```

`f` is like  **"filename.tif"**, but I want it to be **"filename"**.

Comment: QFileInfo::baseName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` `fileName` with "." as separator like this:

```
QString croped_fileName=fileName.split(".",QString::SkipEmptyParts).at(0);
```

or use `section` function of QString to take the first part before "." like this:

```
QString croped_fileName=fileName.section(".",0,0);
```

Comment: This won't work if the filename (without extension) also contains a `.`.

Comment: I guess Shf also didn't know that `QFileInfo` already provides this. I vote for re-accepting.

Comment: `QFileInfo::baseName` is not static, it needs `QFileInfo` object to use baseName or completeBaseName. And for this case it is unnecessary, but in general, yeah, that would be more elegant.

Comment: This is only acceptable in the context of the question (thus no downvote), but very wrong in a general context, as leemes already pointed out. The OP should really consider accepting Angew's answer.

Answer (score 101):

`QFileInfo` has two functions for this:

```
QString QFileInfo::completeBaseName () const
```

Returns file name with shortest extension removed (`file.tar.gz` -> `file.tar`)

```
QString QFileInfo::baseName () const
```

Returns file name with longest extension removed (`file.tar.gz` -> `file`)

Comment: @MartinDrozdik That is an entirely misleading comment. The caching actually makes `QFileInfo` avoid requesting the same information multiple times, and is only filled on-demand. There are no periodic checks to update the cached information, which is why functions like `QFileInfo::refresh` and `setCaching(false)` exist.

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer I checked the documentation and it seems that you're right for both Qt 4 and Qt 5. I wrote my comment quite some time ago and don't remember the exact situation that prompted me to write it. However I had some performance issues back then. I hope my comment did not do a lot of damage. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Maybe with an example it'd be better ;)

Comment: SHORTEST extension, or last?

Comment: @Oscar Last, effectively. Shortest in the sense "the shortest suffix of the string that forms an extension."

Comment: Let's just say last.

Answer (score 11):

To cope with filenames containing multiple dots, look for the last one and take the substring until that one.

```
int lastPoint = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
QString fileNameNoExt = fileName.left(lastPoint);
```

Of course this can (and should) be written as a helper function for reuse:

```
inline QString withoutExtension(const QString & fileName) {
    return fileName.left(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't know it. My suggestion was more general: If you write code which is most likely to be reused, move it into a function.

Answer (score 3):

To get absolute path without extension for `QFileInfo fileInfo("/a/path/to/foo.tar.gz")` you can use:

```
QDir(file_info.absolutePath()).filePath(file_info.baseName());
```

to get `"/a/path/to/foo"` or

```
QDir(file_info.absolutePath()).filePath(file_info.completeBaseName());
```

to get `"/a/path/to/foo.tar"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QString::split` and use the `.` as the place where to split it.

`QStringList list1 = str.split(".");`

That will return a `QStringList` with `{"filename", "extenstion"}`.  Now you can get your filename without the extension.

Comment: This won't work if the filename (without extension) also contains a `.`.

Comment: @leemes sure, but OP didn't specify that, did he?

Comment: Well, "without extension" is a bit ambiguous, especially when dealing combined extensions like ".tar.gz", but in his example, only removing the last part makes more sense.

Comment: While a nice a solution this won't work if the filename has already "." in its name part like This.is.a_correct_file.txt